# Extract a single email address from Word doc and apply it to the TO: field of an Outlook email

Tags: vba, email, outlook, ms-word

The company I work for emails letters to hundreds of people a day.  The letter templates vary, as does the location in the letter of the data that I want.  I already have VBA code that handles most of the steps for the user, including attaching the letter as PDF to an Outlook email and populating the subject and body.  Currently, the issue is that human error is causing typos and misdirection when the users type in the email address that the letter is going TO.  So I'm trying to add a section in this code that searches the document for an email address (there will always only be one email address in the doc, but might be in different place), and then copies that email and puts it in the TO line of the Outlook email.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
Sub EmailDocumentAsPDFfinal()


Dim SourceDoc As Document
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMessage As Object
Dim TempFileName As Variant
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim DefaultName As String
Dim UserAnswer As Long
Dim x As Long

  Set SourceDoc = ActiveDocument

  TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

  If SourceDoc.Path <> "" Then
    DefaultName = Left(SourceDoc.Name, InStrRev(SourceDoc.Name, ".") - 1)
  Else
    DefaultName = SourceDoc.Name
  End If

TempFileName = "DocName"

  ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
   OutputFileName:=TempFilePath & TempFileName & ".pdf", _
   ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

  On Error Resume Next
    Set OutlookApp = GetObject(class:="Outlook.Application") 'Handles if Outlook is already open
  Err.Clear
    If OutlookApp Is Nothing Then Set OutlookApp = CreateObject(class:="Outlook.Application") 'If not, open Outlook

    If Err.Number = 429 Then
      MsgBox "Outlook could not be found, aborting.", 16, "Outlook Not Found"
      Exit Sub
    End If
  On Error GoTo 0

  Set OutlookMessage = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

  On Error Resume Next
    With OutlookMessage
     .To = ""
     .CC = ""
     .BCC = ""
     .Subject = "This is the letter you requested"
     .Body = "Please let us know if you have any questions."
     .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & ".pdf"
     .Display
    End With
  On Error GoTo 0

  Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & ".pdf"

  Set OutlookMessage = Nothing
  Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following block to your code (preferrably in the beginning after you define `SourceDoc`) - it looks for the email using wildcards and returns a full string to the `EmAdr` variable, which you can use in the `.To` line of your outlook sender code

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim EmAdr as String

Set rng = SourceDoc.Content

    With Rng.Find
        .Text = "*@*.*"
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True

        If .Execute Then
           EmAdr = rng.Text
        Else
          MsgBox "Email not found"
        End If
    End With
```

If this helps, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I changed '.Text = "*@*.*"' to '.Text = [A-z,0-9]{1,}\@[A-z,0-9,\.]{1,}' because with the original, I was getting the entire contents of the letter leading up to the email address, and then the email address itself.  Now with the change I'm getting only the email address, but if there's a special character (such as a period) in the first part of the address, I only get what's after the period.

Comment: ` With rng.Find
        .Text = "<[0-9A-ÿ.\-]{1,}\@[0-9A-ÿ\-.]{1,}([^13 -/\:-\@\\-`\{-¿])"
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True

        If .Execute Then
           EmAdr = rng.Text
        Else
          MsgBox "Email not found"
        End If
    End With`

Comment: <http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1> this might help